# XGBoost Installation Error on Mac

Tags: python, xgboost

When the below code is run on Mac gives the error No module named 'xgboost.sklearn'. Also, tried changing xgboost.sklearn to xgboost. This gave the error: cannot import name 'XGBClassifier'

from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
```

Answer (score 0):

The XGBClassifier is not included in the scikit-learn. The XGBoost provides the normal XGBoost instance and the scikit-learn version. So, you need to install the XGBoost, and import the XGBClassifier from the xgboost by using:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
```